# Java 6 to Java 8 Migration Issue

Tags: java, java-8, migration, java-6

I have tried to update legacy code from java 6 to java 8 by updating pom (maven-compile-plugin source and target and javax javaee-web-api.

When I change the server java to jdk 8 and try to run it I get the following error:

> Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer 
>   load method java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization 
>   error at 
>   org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class 
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer can not access a member of class 
>   my.package.$Proxy280 with modifiers "public">       at
>   sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)

Is there any code which I need to update to fix the above error?

Comment: You should upgrade your Glassfish server along with the JDK.

Comment: There was an interface with default access level in services package, on adding public modifier this issue solved.